# MonoDevelop with Visual Studio Websites

Tags: monodevelop

In Visual Studio you can create a Website, which doesn't have a solution or project file, it just opens it up when you point Visual Studio at the right virtual directory / IIS website. Is there a way to do this with MonoDevelop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, MonoDevelop only supports solution based web sites.